# Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log)

Tags: r

I am getting error for the following execution :

```
library(adegenet)
library(ape)
dat <- haploGen(seq.l=1e4, repro=function(){sample(1:4,1)}, gen.time=1, t.max=3)
plot(dat, main="Simulated data")

#Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
#  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
#Calls: plot -> plot -> plot.default -> xy.coords
```

Same code works in rweb online !!

I think the problem is with the package.
So I tried updating the package and I get the following error.

```
** preparing package for lazy loading Error : object ‘renderPrint’ is not exported by 'namespace:shiny' 
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘adegenet’ * removing ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/adegenet’
* restoring previous ‘~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.14/adegenet’ Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘adegenet’ had non-zero exit status
```

Also I have similar problems with other plots with same packages loaded. This is the code:

```
dat <- haploGen(seq.l=1e4, repro=function(){sample(1:4,1)}, gen.time=1, t.max=3) 
res <- seqTrack(dat, mu=0.0001, haplo.length=1e4)
plot(res, main="seqTrack reconstruction")
```

This is the plot I get. 
    [docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgeG1hRHdLS0pPZHM/edit](http://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgeG1hRHdLS0pPZHM/edit) 
Actual plot should look like 
    [docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgcDNPZW1TMFBxeEE/edit](http://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgcDNPZW1TMFBxeEE/edit)

This was tested on rweb online too. I have tested on Rstudio as well. It doesn't make any difference.

Version Details =>
Ubuntu 12.04, 
adegenet version 1.3.1, 
R version 2.4.1

New version of the adegenet package is 1.4.1 and it is not getting installed from the CRAN repository in the first place (updating error is a separate issue in itself as I have mentioned above).

Comment: this is reproducible. I have taken the example from r official documents.

Comment: I'm not getting any error while running your code. Everything looks fine. For some reason your R calls `plot.defaut`. Maybe restart R or reinstall the relevant packages

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking the question. In rweb online, it is working fine. But I am getting the error in my system. But everything else works fine !

I too though of the same thing, reinstalling. But that would give me more problems. I am unable to post further questions. Asking questions is banned !
Also I am not able to install some of the libraries directly from R. So I am stuck with older versions of the packages. What shall I do ?

Comment: Clicking Answer Your Question or Clarifying it more difficult as compared to clicking the vote down button.. Thank you. I think I had enough time spent over here.

Comment: I haven't vote you down. What OS are you using and what GUI? Have you tried Rstudio? https://www.rstudio.com/

Comment: @DavidArenburg Ubuntu 12.04. Rstudio gives the same error in a bright red colour. Rest is same.

Also I have similar problem to related to plot with same packages loaded.
This is the code:

  dat <- haploGen(seq.l=1e4, repro=function(){sample(1:4,1)}, gen.time=1, t.max=3) 
  res <- seqTrack(dat, mu=0.0001, haplo.length=1e4)
  plot(res, main="seqTrack reconstruction")

This is the plot I get.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgeG1hRHdLS0pPZHM/edit

Actual plot should look like
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxRqodN_w-mgcDNPZW1TMFBxeEE/edit
This was tested on rweb online.

Comment: I'm not sure what going on really. It seems like your problem is with R iteself rather with a certain function. If I were you, I'd look on web on how to fix it. I don't think I can help you in any way. sorry

Comment: I am searching for it. I found similar question in some mailing list. Efforts to find a solution are in vain. I am sure this is a valid question. I am trying to figure out anyway. Thanks for your time.

Comment: +1 for getting more specific. I hope you'll get the help you need. Is this the only package you having trouble with? I have the feeling you have a general problem with your R

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks. Yes the above mentioned package is the problematic one. Other packages' functions are working fine.
In fact, only that specific plot function is haunting me as I have mentioned and given links to the plots as well.

Comment: R 2.4.1 was released in December 2006. Can you update your R version? Otherwise you may need to look for old versions of the packages (you can look through the archive on CRAN).

Comment: @shujaa I got errors in updating the package as I have mentioned in question. I am just using just a version that is 1 below the latest available version of the adegenet package. In fact, I have manually downloaded packages from archive and installed it as I was not able to install it directly (which is a long story and problem in itself!!). I didn't post a question for it as I have somehow resolved (hacked) it by trying out different older versions.